# Access Network Drive That is Marked Red Rather than Green Before Running a Process That Accesses a File on The Network Drive

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written an application that accesses and reads a file on network drive.  If the end-user has just booted the computer and logged into the VPN the network drive shows a Red Mark rather than a Green Mark.  Prior to clicking the button to run the process the end-user must first open the network drive.  If the end-user doesn't manually access the network drive prior to clicking the button the application throws an exception that the drive cannot be accessed.

How can I use C# Winforms programmatically to access the network drive prior to running the process?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "F:\PATH\FILE"
use "\SERVER\DRIVE_NAME\PATH\FILE"